# What does <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ColumnName") %> in the Item Template do exactly?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding, datalist

Iam using `DataList` for the first time. Every thing works fine and I am able to see the data in the screen.
I am making use of this code in the item template.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
    <FooterTemplate>          
    </FooterTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>              
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>          
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"AA") %>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BB") %>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CC") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

This is the `DataTable` that I am binding

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("AA");
dt.Columns.Add("BB");
dt.Columns.Add("CC");

dt.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");
dt.Rows.Add("10", "20", "30");
dt.Rows.Add("100", "200", "300");
dt.Rows.Add("1000", "2000", "3000");

DataList1.DataSource = dt;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

What does `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ColumnName")` do exactly.?
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Addendum to the answers below. Since `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"memberName")` is *late-bound*, performance will suffer. See this article for the early-bound - and therefore more efficient and debug-friendly - syntax: http://www.devcurry.com/2011/02/how-to-avoid-databindereval-in-aspnet.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Argument 1: `Container.DataItem` refers to the `datasource` that is bound to the current container.

Argument 2: The public property on the `DataItem` which should be evaluated.

So Eval uses reflection to evaluate the public property on the `DataItem`.

ex:

In you case it evaluates the `BB` column on the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 8):

The following lines will be executed as many times as the number of rows in the Table.

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"AA") %>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BB") %>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CC") %>
```

Each time *Container.DataItem* will have the corresponding *DataRowView* of the rows in the datatable.

What happens in the item is similar to this code.

```
DataView dataView = new DataView(dt);
foreach (DataRowView dataRow in dataView)
{              
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DataBinder.Eval(dataRow,"AA").ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DataBinder.Eval(dataRow,"BB").ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DataBinder.Eval(dataRow,"CC").ToString());
}
```

And the output obtained will be

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   10
>   20
>   30
>   100
>   200
>   300
>   1000
>   2000
>   3000